# PHP separate id for every div

Tags: php, html, mysqli

to be honest this is more of a how to then help with code i already have. So i hope this is okay, else of course i will delete my question again. Anyway here goes i have a site with boxes, with a picture headline and a submit button. All the info in these boxes is being delivered, from my database. And of course in my database i also have a id cell, and if i try to echo out the id cell with the rest of the info in the box it shows up fine. But when i try to assign the id output variable to a header location, i do for some weird reason always get the id 3. Eventhough the id´s shows up perfectly fine, in the boxes. I have included my php code and i am still a beginner to php so sorry for this noob question. :)

```
 session_start();
        include 'connection.php';
    $sqlSelect = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM inspi");
    while ($feed=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSelect))
    {   
         $id = $feed['id'];
         if(isset($_POST['readArticle']))
         {
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            header("Location:"."redirect.php?".SID.$idArticle);
         }
        ?>



    <div class="contentBoxOne">
        <img width="100%" height="170px" src="userpics/<?php echo $feed['image']; ?>">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="readArticle" class="readArticle" value="Læs nu!">
        </form>
        <?php $idArticle= $feed['id'];?>
        <h2><?php echo $feed['headline'];?></h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting $idArticle at the bottom of the loop but trying to use it at the top so it will be pulling it from the previous result. Try:

```
while ($feed=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlSelect)){   

    $idArticle= $feed['id'];
    $sid = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['readArticle']))
    {
        header("Location:"."redirect.php?".$sid.$idArticle);
    }

    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: It did change the id but now it just for some reason takes the id of 5? :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put div inside the loop.

I also replaced the header redirect with form action attribute (you may want to replace method `POST` with `GET` instead).

`ID` is passed with a hidden field

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$sqlSelect = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM inspi");
while ($feed=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlSelect))
{   
     $id = (int)$feed['id'];
?>

    <div class="contentBoxOne">
        <img width="100%" height="170px" src="userpics/<?php echo $feed['image']; ?>">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <form method="post" action="redirect.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="readArticle" class="readArticle" value="Læs nu!">
        </form>
        <h2><?php echo $feed['headline']; ?></h2>
        debug: <pre><?php print_r($feed); ?></pre>
    </div>
<?php } // end of while loop ?>
```

Comment: Still just getting id 5 on all the boxes :( but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: changed from fetch_array to fetch_assoc and added debug code into `div`.  Maybe that gives you some ideas what may be wrong.

Comment: whats in your database? all 5-s? do you get div for each row with its data (debug array)?

Comment: i do get a div for each row in my database and so far the id numbers in my database goes from 1-5 which means i have 5 divs and my page to me it seems like it just takes the highest id for some reason?